# increase the progressbar percentage

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

I've the below piece of code, where there is a progress bar that has to progressed.

```
public void createFiles(String srcText, String destText, JTextArea outputTextArea, JProgressBar progressBar) {
        String zipFilePath = srcText;
        String destDirectory = destText;
        UnZip unzipper = new UnZip();
        File dir = new File(zipFilePath);
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        System.out.println(files.length);
        double pBarInt = (double) files.length / 100;
        int count = 1;
        System.out.println(count);
        if (null != files) {
            for (int fileIntList = 0; fileIntList < files.length; fileIntList++) {
                System.out.println("coun in vlocj " + count);
                String ss = files[fileIntList].toString();
                if (null != ss && ss.length() > 0) {
                    try {
                        if (files[fileIntList].isDirectory())
                            continue;
                        unzipper.unzip(zipFilePath + ss.substring(ss.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, ss.length()), destDirectory,
                                outputTextArea);
                        if ((fileIntList + 1) % pBarInt == 0) {
                            progressBar.setValue(count);
                            progressBar.update(progressBar.getGraphics());
                            count += 1;
                        }

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here the value of `files.length` is 25.

My question is, since there are 25 files 1% of them would be 2.5%, can i increase my progress bar for every 4 files processed as 10% or can i show 2.5% whenever a file has been processed.

If `files.length` is greater than 100, i'm able to do it, but unable to understand for files less than 100.

please let me know how can i get this done.

Thanks

Comment: Did your code above not work?

Comment: Hi @tinysunlight, this worked, but the progress bar stopped at 24%, and  24 files were created

Comment: You should only access Swing components on the Event Dispatch Thread. Please ltake alook at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ProgressBarDemoProject/src/components/ProgressBarDemo.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might just have to set the maximum correctly. E.g.:

```
progressBar.setMaximum(files.length);
```

To get only the files and not the directories in the first place do:

```
File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {   
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file, String name) {
        return !file.isDirectory();
    }
});
```

I would write the whole bit like this:

```
File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {   
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file, String name) {
        return !file.isDirectory();
    }
});
progressBar.setMaximum(files.length);
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    File f = files[i];
    try {
       unzipper.unzip(f.getAbsolutePath(), destDirectory, outputTextArea);
       progressBar.setValue(i);
       progressBar.update(progressBar.getGraphics());
   } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

And you might want to dispatch it in a thread. See the comment on your question.

Comment: This is stopping at 16% :(

Comment: I guess it is because you have a lot of directories in there. So files.length is actually much bigger than 25. You have to first go through the list of files and count the number that are not directories. You could also first filter the list and then iterate over the filtered one.

Comment: Hi Friend, this help me alot. Thanks for it. also this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218422/get-the-number-of-files-in-a-folder-omitting-subfolders helped me. Thanks Again :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need this condition `(fileIntList + 1) % pBarInt == 0`

You should be setting the progress bar count as a percentage of the total files. Try using

```
progress.setValue(100);
....
int progressBarValue = count * 100/files.length;
progressBar.setValue(progressBarValue);
```

For accuracy use the correct files.length - ignoring directories.

Comment: This goes only till 4% :(. Here is my code added `progressBar.setValue(100);System.out.println(count);if (null != files) {
   for (int fileIntList = 0; fileIntList < files.length; fileIntList++) {System.out.println("coun in vlocj " + count);String ss = files[fileIntList].toString();if (null != ss && ss.length() > 0) {try {if (files[fileIntList].isDirectory())continue;unzipper.unzip(zipFilePath + ss.substring(ss.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, ss.length()), destDirectory,outputTextArea);
int progressBarValue = count * 100 / files.length;progressBar.setValue(progressBarValue);`