# How to count file in resources folder inside the project?

Tags: java, file, count, resources, directory

I need help with counting files in resources folder. I need it to work when I export project as Runnable JAR file. I'm making simple photo viewer and I have to know when stop changing the picture when it's the last one.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687444/counting-the-number-of-files-in-a-directory-using-java

Comment: I already tried this and it's not working for resources folder...
int counter=new File("resources").list().length; 
When I gave some other path like: 
new File("E:/resources").list().length; than it works. 
So what path I should give to make it work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758105/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-files-in-a-folder-within-a-jar