# By java how to count file numbers in a directory without list()

Tags: java, java-io

Without using `file.list()` or `Files.list(path)`, how to count file numbers in a directory?

I just want a number, no detail. Given me a quick way please.

Comment: See [this duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/687444/5743988). If you cannot find a solution there, it's probably because `list()` is the best way to do it.

Comment: I u are using unix then you can use the unix "ls -1 | wc -l" tric in java

Comment: What is the reason behind not using list? That answer may help provide you the right solution

Comment: Why don't you want to use these methods ? Is it a programming challenge or something ? Do you have performance problems with these methods ?

Comment: @dganesh2002 because If there are too many files, list() is expensive. I just wanna known the number, I think underlying file system may have a count record, obviously read that record is fastest

Comment: @Spotted I have too many little files, list() or stream is expensive. I just wanna know the number. I think underlying file system may have a count record, obviously read that record is fastest

Comment: @FredSuvn Even this is already a bit old. I added some timings of different ways. Which solution did you chose in the meantime?

Comment: @SubOptimal here no solution is approving to me. May underlying file system doesn't have a counter for file number?

Comment: @FredSuvn The tests were executed on a XFS filesystem (non SSD drive) which also don't have a file counter in the directory node. I don't know which filesystem would provide such information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your only concern is to not create a `List<File>` you might use the `Stream API`.

```
long count = Files.list(Paths.get(path))
        .filter(p -> p.toFile().isFile())
        .count();
System.out.println("count = " + count);
```

**edit** The snippet is not meant to be fast. It was only provied for the requirement not to use `list()` or `listFiles()`. ;-)

Following a small comparison of different ways of counting the number of files in a directory containing two million files.

All commands are executed twice. First execution is with dropped file cache and the second execution followed right after the first one.

```
              | ls    | dir.list() | dir.listFiles() | Files.list(path)
--------------+-------+------------+-----------------+------------------
dropped cache | 9,120 |   5,518    |      5,879      |      59,175
filled cache  |   946 |   1,992    |      2,401      |      51,179
```

times in milliseconds (the comma is the thousands separator)

Below the executed commands in detail.

**ls**

```
ls -f /tmp/huge-dir | wc -l
```

**dir.list()**

```
File hugeDir = new File("/tmp/huge-dir");
int numberFiles = hugeDir.list().length;
```

**dir.listFile()**

```
File hugeDir = new File("/tmp/huge-dir");
int numberFiles = hugeDir.listFiles().length;
```

**Files.list(path)**

```
Path path = Paths.get("/tmp/huge-dir");
long numberFiles = Files.list(path)
        .filter(p -> p.toFile().isFile())
        .count();
```

Based on those figures. Using `dir.list().length` seems to be not a bad solution.