# How to add scheduler and custome checks around camel file processing

Tags: file, apache-camel

Before explaining my problem I would state here that I am completely new to camel file processing. I have a requirement to read the file from a directory do some processing and delete them. This was a very high level requirement and I am able to achieve this using camel. But now I've got some new requirements as stated below. Need help on that.

1. Create this application as a job and trigger it by reading another directory where some specific files would be dropped other wise it should kicked of by its own every 15-20 minutes.
2. Before triggering the actual application make sure that the directory has some specific number of files present (say 25 files)
3. If all files are present - execute a method to create a unique tracking ID for all these 25 files. If I have a unique ID how can I make it available through multiple routes?

As of now I have tried implementing `routepolicy` but since I have never used it earlier I need some guidance so that I can go ahead with this.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Separe your route logic from route triggering

```
<route id="TriggerFromFile">
    <from uri="file:triggerFolder" />
    <log message="Triggered from file" />
    <to uri="direct:startLogic" />
<route>

<route id="TriggerFromTimer">
    <from uri="timer:triggerTimer?period=15m" />
    <log message="Triggered from timer" />
    <to uri="direct:startLogic" />
</route>

<route id="Logic>
    <from uri="direct:startLogic" />
    <to uri="..." />
</route>
```

### 2. Count the number of files and use that as a filter

Define a bean that [counts the number of files in the dir](https://stackoverflow.com/q/687444/423955), set that number
as body and validate using a filter.

```
<route id="TriggerFromFile">
    <from uri="file:triggerFolder" />
    <log message="Triggered from file" />
    <to uri="direct:countFile" />
<route>

<route id="TriggerFromTimer">
    <from uri="timer:triggerTimer?period=15m" />
    <log message="Triggered from timer" />
    <to uri="direct:countFile" />
</route>

<route id="FileCount">
    <from uri="direct:countFile" />
    <to uri="bean:countFilesInDir" />
    <log message="There are ${body} files the directory" />
    <filter>
        <simple>${body} >= 25</simple>
        <to uri="direct:startLogic" />
    </filter>
</route>

<route id="Logic">
    <from uri="direct:startLogic" />
    <to uri="..." />
</route>
```

### 3. Set a Header to your Exchange's message before sending it to other routes

When Camel sends an Exchange between routes, headers and properties are copied.
Calculate a unique id in some way (concatenate file names, md5 of content, file modification timestamp....) and set it in a Header.
An header can hold any java object.

Comment: thanks @Alessandro , this would help. Will come back if any questions.