# group files based on fixed size chunks using java

Tags: java

I have a folder containing multiple files. I want to create folders based on chunk size provided by the user. Those folders need to be created in same directory as the files. And then, I want to move those files to folders. Number of folders= no. of files/chunk size. so if there are 10 files and chunk size is 2, then 5 folders should be created with 2 files each.

Comment: Ok. What have you tried so far? You have a specification, and now it is time to start coding up a proof of concept. Remember that SO is not a coding for hire site, so no one is going to write this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Is the chunk size really need to be variable or can it be a constant?
Because to calculate the total number of files in the folder itself is a heavy activity as it needs to list the files.

So if the total number of files is huge, calculating the number of folders will take long. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34747673/10117515).

However if chunk size is fixed then you can get the `DirectoryStream`, iterate over it move the number of files = chunk size to the new directories.